# Is $f(x)=0$ the only function that is both even and odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is $f(x)=0$ the only function that is both even and odd?

Thanks to you.

Comment: If a function is even, you have $f(x)=f(-x)$. If a function is odd, then $f(x)=-f(-x)$. Hence at any point
$$
f(x)=-f(-x)=f(-x).
$$
The only number equal to its additive inverse is $0$.

Comment: It is indeed. Simply use the definitions of odd and even functions, that should do it.

Comment: Granted $2\neq 0$

Comment: it may be worth pointing out that, even though there is only one *function* that is both even and odd, there are many *relations* that are both even and odd, in the sense of symmetry with respect to the $y$-axis and the origin, respectively. for example, the relation determined by $x^2+y^2=1$ is both even and odd in the sense of symmetries.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ be an even and an odd function.  That is, $f(-x) = f(x) = -f(x)$.  In particular, from this we have:

$$f(x) = -f(x)$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: $$f(x)=-f(x)\implies 2f(x)=0\implies f(x)=0$$ right???

Comment: please tell me!

Comment: That's it!  You got it.

Comment: As long as $2\neq 0$.

Comment: Why as lon as $2\neq0$

Comment: @npisinp: It's sort of a joke, but there are certain number systems (rings or fields) in which $1+1=0$, so you could say $2=0$.  This is called having [characteristic 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29).  In those number systems, this argument would not work.  Of course, in the real numbers, $2 \ne 0$, so this argument is perfectly valid here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.